# Python splitting lists to intersections iteratively

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is splitting some lists, based on their common elements, with an identifier of which list they came from. So, first build a list that contains all of the common items in all lists, then a list with those existing in a subset of lists etc.

It's better to explain it with an example:

```
list A : [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
list B : [ 2, 6, 10, 11 , 13 ]
list C : [ 3, 6, 8, 9 , 11 ]
===> OUTPUT :
( [ A, B, C ] : [6] ) ,
( [ A, B ] : [ 2, 10 ] ) ,
( [ A, C ] : [ 8 ] ) 
( [ B, C ] : [ 11 ] ) ,
( [ A ] : [ 4 ] ) ,
( [ B ] : [ 13] ) ,
( [ C ] : [ 3 , 9 ]
```

I can find a way of working through that in paper :

- find interestion A&B , then remove these items from A and B. `A&B =  [2,6,10], A = [ 4,8] , B = [ 11,13 ]`
- then find interection of `A&B&C = [ 6 ]`, and now `A&B becomes [ 2, 10 ]`.
- continue like this iteratively and every time update my lists, with their new content etc.

But the above does not seem so pythonic to me - and I am a fairly new user to Python. Can I use any libraries to help me do so? I am planning to use python 2.7 but if going to Python 3 can help me I can do so.

Comment: Use sets for this problem.

Comment: What above? You only posted *specifications*.

Comment: This looks like a *lattice* construction.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I mean if I go through my bullets I will just end up having loops and nested loops. I thought that Python might have something I can use - otherwise the solution will be identical like using C++ and vectors, or Java an Arraylists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, and I'm sure this is not the best way to do it, but a quick thing that maybe can help.

If you start with a dictionary that associates each list to a letter:

```
lists = {
 'A' : [2,4,6,8,10],
 'B' : [2,6,10,11,13],
 'C' : [3,6,8,9,11]
 }
```

You can then map the occurrences with something similar to this (if you're not familiar with defaultdict or the collections library check it out, it's awesome)

```
from collections import defaultdict

occurrences = defaultdict(list)

for letter, values in lists.items():
    for value in values:
        occurrences[value].append(letter)
```

then you use another dict to group the occurrences dict by values

```
result = defaultdict(list)
for value, letters in occurrences.items():
    result[tuple(letters)].append(value)
```

and you get

```
 {('A',): [4],
  ('A', 'B'): [2, 10],
  ('A', 'B', 'C'): [6],
  ('A', 'C'): [8],
  ('B',): [13],
  ('B', 'C'): [11],
  ('C',): [3, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

are u on programming competition or something ?

```
>>> A=[ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
>>> B =[ 2, 6, 10, 11 , 13 ]
>>> C =[ 3, 6, 8, 9 , 11 ]
>>> r=set(A+B+C)
>>> l=[[] for i in r]
>>> for index,i in enumerate(r):
    add=[]
    if i in A:
        add.append("a")
    if i in B:
        add.append("b")
    if i in C:
        add.append("c")
    l[index].extend(add)


>>> d={}
>>> for i in r:
    d[i]=0


>>> for index,i in enumerate(d):
    d[i]=l[index]


>>> final={}
>>> for i in d.values():
    final[tuple(i)]=[]


>>> for k,v in d.items():
    final[tuple(v)].append(k)


>>> final
{('c',): [3, 9], ('a',): [4], ('a', 'c'): [8], ('a', 'b'): [2, 10], ('a', 'b', 'c'): [6], ('b', 'c'): [11], ('b',): [13]}
>>>
```

Comment: no need for spped - just want to write a script that will do some filtering on data I get from an api. Will check the above thanks!